# how to change a programs icon using tkinter on macos?

Tags: python, macos

extreme begginer here so please excuse me if im asking a dumb question.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry("420x420")
window.title('gui program')

icon = PhotoImage(file='frog.gif')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)

window.mainloop()
```

for some reason it doesnt change the icon on my program. still shows the feather icon.
also, I couldnt use a .png image and it does work on my windows so why is that ?
thanks a lot!

i tried changing the icon but it doesnt change (although the code seems to work on a windows pc)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, your code changes the app icon as expected on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You say it works on Windows and the comment above says it works on their Mac system, so I suspect the issue is that the frog.gif file is not being found on the system you're experiencing the problem with. To determine what directory your code is expecting the file to be in, add this to your code.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If your file is not in the directory shown, either move it to that directory of supply the full path.